# In Excel 2010, how do you convert a multi-data type column (strings & dates) into a single date data type?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I was given an Excel document.

In the data there is a column of dates formatted 5/20/2014. Half the data in that column is formatted as a date. The other half is formatted as text. When I try and format the entire column as a text the cells formatted as dates become their numeric  equivalent (integers). If I try and format the entire column as a date, the cells formatted as text stay text values until I double click the cell and hit enter; then they become formatted as a date.

How do I change the format from text to date without having to double click in thousands and thousands of cells?

Answer (score 1):

Use the formula `=IFERROR(DATEVALUE(A1),A1)` (where A1 is the beginning cell of your date column) at the top of a new column, fill it down to the end of your table, then copy the new column and use Paste Special -> Values.  Format the new column as Date.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one answer, but I would copy from the last date cell that is correct, Click the cell and hit ctrl-c. Then use your favorite method to select the destination cells, unless there are 40,000 rows I usually just click the first cell hold the click and drag to the end of the range, then use `PASTE SPECIAL` and select `formats`.

You could also copy a single cell, then select the entire column that cell is in by clicking it's header... again use `paste special` and `formats`.

The advantage to copying an existing format is if there are other setting to the format than just date mode that were set, they will also be copied.